# So whats wrong with the embedded database?

Tags: bamboo

Atlassian says the embedded DB is only for evaluation purposes and isn't sutible for production.

Why not? I have found zero docs on why I should move to an external DB. What problems will I run into running the embedded HSQL DB? What about it makes it not production ready?

What if I have a client that has a production bamboo installation but they are still using the embedded DB. What do I tell them, move to an external DB because.... why? Because Jira says so? Hey it works fine so why would we change it?

At this point I should be able to say something about its capacity, reliability, stability, management, when it starts to fall over, etc

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! The docs at Atlassian say nothing about why it's unsafe to run the embedded db and also what the risk exactly are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, HSQL Database is not [transaction safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and it can cause a irrecoverable data lose and I would say that's the main reason for not using it in production.

For example, you may encounter a corruption in database in case of sudden power loss. Reason is, HSQL stores every transactions in memory first prior to writing it in the db file.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that it is a completely unsupported configuration and as such Atlassian Support will not help you if anything goes wrong with your installation.

If you're fine with that, continue as is, otherwise, move to a supported configuration.